# Every time I try to execute the code below, it displays the error "Incorrect syntax near 'B'."

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project and I need to declare the query below. But every time I try to execute it, it displays the error "Incorrect syntax near 'B'."

```
    DECLARE @strLineCode VARCHAR (20)
    SET @strLineCode = 'CDP'

    DECLARE @strSQL VARCHAR(5000)  
    SET @strSQL = 'SELECT B.strCurrentLineCode,   
    strLineMachineNo, strSAPAssetNum, B.strResourceSubType   
    FROM tblMachMaster A  
    INNER JOIN vwResourceMaster B   
    ON A.strResourceNumber = B.strResourceNumber' 

    SET @strSQL = @strSQL + 'WHERE B.strCurrentLineCode = ''' + @strLineCode + ''' '

    EXEC(@strSQL)
```

I tried executing it without declaring the query and it works just fine. Send help :(

Comment: You miss blank here `strSQL + 'WHERE` must be `strSQL + ' WHERE `

Comment: Your concatinated string looks like `ON A.strResourceNumber = B.strResourceNumberWHERE`

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my problem!

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @strLineCode = 'CDP';
PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT B.strCurrentLineCode,   
strLineMachineNo, strSAPAssetNum, B.strResourceSubType   
FROM tblMachMaster A  
INNER JOIN vwResourceMaster B   
ON A.strResourceNumber = B.strResourceNumber WHERE B.strCurrentLineCode = ?' ;
EXECUTE stmt 
 USING @strLineCode;
```

You can try above code.

Here I had used [`PREPARE and EXECUTE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)  Statement.

Using which you can simply execute your dynamic query.

One more thing you missed `';'` after every line of code. In MySQL statement is always end with `';'` only.

Comment: Thank you for your help!